# Reload current view with tab bar

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

is it possible to create a refresh button in a tab bar that just refreshes the current view? And don't change to another view?

How could this be done?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a `UITabbar` and its `- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` delegate method.

I won't suggest doing that, though, because that's not how tabbar normally works.

Since you want it to act like a tool bar, why not just use `UIToolbar`?

Comment: I know, maybe it's not a perfect solution. But i need a tab bar for other purposes. Right know im setting the current view to delegate for the tab bar and update. Is this a stupid solution?